# recursive Add python matrix sparse

Tags: python, syntax-error, sparse-matrix

I am new to Python - I came from matlab. I am trying to compile this code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

n=3
dim=2^n

sx = np.array([[0,1],[1,0]])
sy = np.array([[0,-1j],[1j,0]])
sz = np.array([[1,0],[0,-1]])
ssx= sparse.csr_matrix(sx)
ssy= sparse.csr_matrix(sy)
ssz= sparse.csr_matrix(sz)


expon1=np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(n-1):
    expon1[i,i]=1
    expon1[i+1,i]=1
expon1[0,n-1]=1
expon1[n-1,n-1]=1
expon2=np.identity(n)

Sigs1=sparse.csr_matrix(0,(dim, dim))
for j in range(n-1):
    Sig1=sparse.csr_matrix(1)
    for i in range(n-1):
        Sig1=sparse.kron(Sig1,ssx.power(expon1[i,j]))
    Sigs1= Sigs1+Sig1
```

After running `python3 sparse.py [name of file]`, the terminal prints the following text:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sparse.py", line 31, in <module>
    Sigs1= Sigs1+Sig1
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 341, in __add__
    raise ValueError("inconsistent shapes")
ValueError: inconsistent shapes
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt go through your whole code, but looking at it I can say your problem is probably here.

```
n=3
dim=2^n
```

This `^` operator in python is for bitwise XOR while this `**` is for power.

Comment: tnx but if remove 

Sigs1=sparse.csr_matrix(0,(dim, dim))
for j in range(n-1):
    Sig1=sparse.csr_matrix(1)
    for i in range(n-1):
        Sig1=sparse.kron(Sig1,ssx.power(expon1[i,j]))
    Sigs1= Sigs1+Sig1

the code works

Comment: if you remove that part your code does not complain, but it doesn't mean it works. The problem with your code is `dim=2^n` is returning 1 instead of 8.

Comment: thx for the advise, i change dim=8, is most practical, but now the problem is in the add: Sigs1= Sigs1+Sig1
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 280, in __add__